# Showing lack of continuity of a function

Tags: calculus

Show that the function $$
f(x) = x \cdot \mathrm{sgn}\sin(1/x), x \neq 0; f(0) = 0
$$
is not continuous on any interval containing $x = 0.$

Comment: Here $\mathrm{sgn}$ stands for the signum function, $\mathrm{sgn}(x) = 1 $ if $x > 0, $ $-1$ if $x < 0$ and $0$ if $x = 0.$

Comment: Is that true then?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about. This book says so, and hence I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

I propose $\lim_{x_\to0}=0$

since $0\leq |\sin(\frac{1}{x})|\leq1$ for $\epsilon>0$ take $0<\delta<\epsilon$.

Then $ \epsilon>|\delta|=|\delta*1||\geq\delta|\sin(\frac{1}{x})||$

Comment: Sure, but it is always bounded right. And when you multiply that by $x,$ shouldn't it go to $0?$

Comment: doesn't this prove we have the limit?